# How to use __gc with /clr

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, clr, managed-c++

This is a simple code I'm trying to build with /clr option with the vc++ project.

```
#using <mscorlib.dll>

__gc class A {

};
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

It gives me this error
`error C4980: '__gc' : use of this keyword requires /clr:oldSyntax command line option'

If I chage clr usage to `/clr:oldSyntax` everything works fine.
 But I need to use `/clr` as my clr option.
is there any other new keyword to use than `__gc` for `/clr` option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__gc` is a keyword of the `Managed C++`. With option /clr you should use the `C++/CLI`. The class can be written like

```
ref class A {
   //...
};
```

Comment: Thais what I was looking for, tnx